# How to create a collection of items referencing collection itself

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm looking for a way of creating a collection of items, each of which would reference the collection itself.

Given:

```
const sources = [1, 2, 3];
```

Expected:

```
const results = [{value:1, items:[{value: 1, items:[{value: 1, items...}, ...]}]}]
```

Broken due to the fact that arrays are copied by value in js code:

```
const source = [1, 2, 3];
let result = [];

result = source.map(value => ({ value, items: result }));
```

I've tried a few things mainly around `(()=> ...)()`, but that gave me nothing. I managed to get it working with items being a function as opposed to value, which isn't exactly what I want.

**Here's the best solution I found so far:**

Code:

```
const source = [1, 2, 3];
let items = [];

items = source.map(value => () => ({ value, items }));
```

Usage:

```
items[1]().items[1]().value // 2
items[1]().items[2]().items[0]().value // 1
```

Comment: Where are 2 and 3 used? The sample looks like an endless collection.

Comment: @briosheje they are. every items should reference the entire collection. This will result in a recursive collection, correct.

Comment: @JsCoder post the JavaScript that fails in returning said expected result.

Comment: @zer00ne what??

Comment: @JsCoder You are required to post something like a function -- something that doesn't work so that we can fix it. Your question is not a request to fix broken code that you are working on -- your question is a request for code  without any work on your side. Post a [mcve]

Comment: @zer00ne there you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations) applies here. In your case, getters would be a good solution:

```
const result = [1, 2, 3].map(value => ({value, get items() { return result; }}));
```

Answer (score 0):

That can't be done in one step. You have to create an array of objects first:

```
 const results = sources.map(value => ({ value }));
```

Then link back:

```
 results.forEach(result => result.items = results);
```

Comment: I was thinking of using curry'ed constructors but I don't have much experience with currying - any value to be had by using it here?